# Filter Dates in sql by months - php,sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a table in sql and in that table I have column with the action date by this format: 2015-08-26 05:54:39

Now I built a system in php and i want to get all the actions that was in the same month.

I try to run that:

```
SELECT * FROM `Expenses` WHERE DateAction between '2015-08-01 00:00:00' and '2015-09-01 00:00:00'
```

and its return the actions dates that was in the same month, But its can return the the action that was in 2015-09-01 00:00:00 so i understand i need to get the last day in the month and put it in the sql query.

How I do that?

Right now this is the call to the sql:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Expenses` WHERE `accountid` = $accountId");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately for you, there's MySQL's `MONTH()` command.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

```
SELECT * FROM `Expenses` WHERE MONTH(DateAction) = 8;
//Selects all rows in the month "August"
```

All months are recorded numerically (1 is January, 2 is February,...... 12 is December). It will always be precise based on your database time and date settings.

If you want to customize your query further (selecting the same year and month), then you can read more about date commands [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT * FROM `Expenses` WHERE Year(DateAction) = '2015' AND MONTH(DateAction) = '8';
//Selects all rows in year 2015 and month "August"
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use YEAR() and MONTH() **or as simple as:**

```
WHERE 
DateAction >= '2015-08-01 00:00:00' 
and 
DateAction  < '2015-09-01 00:00:00'
```

This will not include the september date.

Comment: If you look for performance you should use this, as year() and month() functions take a an overhead for "fetching" the year and month for each. Just to make it clear why I would use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

**I think it may help you** 
Suppose if you want the result or records of August, you may user the query

`SELECT * FROM Expenses WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DateAction,'%c')='8'`